# Comparison of unsorted and mixed case files to select only unique entries

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I've been facing some setbacks while having two way comparison in files.

- File1

  ```
  bill 
  telephone
  address_1
  address_2
  address_3
  city
  postal_code
  ```
- File2

  ```
  Bill
  Bill_ID
  Telephone
  Address_1
  Address_2
  city
  Postal_Code
  ```

I'm trying to populate values which are unique in both the files. So my expected results should look like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
|   File1   |  File2  |
+-----------+---------+
|           | Bill_ID |
| address_3 |         |
+-----------+---------+
```

Things I've tried to achieve it:

- `sdiff` by sorting it lexicographically first but it yielded all columns.
- Alternatively

  ```
  sdiff -Wais File1.txt File2.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
  ```

  but I'll need to run it twice by reversing the files.
- `comm` but having this error

  ```
  comm -23 < (sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)
  bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
  ```
- `diff` but output seems to incorrect.

  ```
  diff File_1 File_2 | grep '^>' | cut -c 3-
  ```

All in these cases I was facing issues with comparison only. I've not been able to move ahead to populate proper table yet.

Comment: Welcome to the site. How large are the files? Are they small enough that a "buffering" approach is still feasible?

Comment: Thank you @AdminBee. Files are not very large. Mean count is about 300 lines/file. Only a few about 50 lines and 480 lines.

Comment: `comm -23 < (sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)` must be `comm -23 <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)`

Comment: You don't REALLY want your output surrounded by pipes and dashes to form sort of a graphical table do you? If not then please show what you DO want the output to look like as we're all making different guesses right now. if you really do want that graphical table output - it's not clear what it'd look like if you had multiple values in each column nor is it obvious why you wouldn't want to have empty file1 cells next to populated file2 cells and vice-versa instead of just both columns packed starting at row 1.

Comment: @EdMorton - Eventually, I'll be needing a tabular form for the the data to be represented. My thought on this was it'll be easier to identify that in one file there is a column but in another file it is not. I'll make a cron job for it so that all other teams can refer easily by looking at file and we can provide remarks on current status in corresponding empty cell. Otherwise, I'll need to ask for a db in which I can give a proper representation. CSVs are also fine; I'll transform files in tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `join` using the lowercase version of the text as the joining key:

```
$ preprocess() { awk -v OFS='\t' '{print tolower($0), $0}' | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1; }
$ join -t $'\t' -o1.2,2.2 -v1 -v2 <(preprocess < file1) <(preprocess < file2)
address_3
        Bill_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **awk**. Works on any number of files out of the box.

Side note: Be careful with <kbd>space</kbd>s at the end of words in your input data.

```
$ awk '{ str=tolower($0); a[str]++; aa[str]=$0; b[str]=b[str]" "FILENAME } 
    END{ for(i in a){ if(a[i]==1){ print aa[i],b[i] } } }' file1 file2
address_3  file1
Bill_ID  file2
```

If you want a table-like output, add one formatting awk to the former. The result is ready to be copy-pasted into e.g. Excel. Of course <kbd>TAB</kbd>s and <kbd>,</kbd> in the strings mess up the formatting.

```
$ awk '{ str=tolower($0); a[str]++; aa[str]=$0; b[str]=b[str]","FILENAME }
    END{ for(i in a){ if(a[i]==1){ print aa[i]b[i] } } }' file1 file2 |
  awk -F ',' '{ nm_a[$NF]++; a[$NF,nm_a[$NF]]=$1 } 
    END{ for(i in nm_a){ printf "%s\t",i; if(max<nm_a[i]){ max=nm_a[i] } }; 
    print "";  for(j=1;j<=max;j++){ for(i in nm_a){ printf "%s\t",a[i,j] } 
    print "" } }' 
file2   file1   
Bill_ID address_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, just like in your posted sample input, the same word doesn't appear multiple times in either input file then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    print ARGV[1], ARGV[2]
}
{ lc = tolower($1) }
NR==FNR {
    file1[lc] = $1
    next
}
lc in file1 {
    delete file1[lc]
    next
}
{
    print "", $1
}
END {
    for (lc in file1) {
        print file1[lc], ""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
file1   file2
        Bill_ID
address_3
```